# REST design: resource verbs or related collections?

Tags: rest

One approach says that you should keep your resource URL simple. We have verb in HTTP and resource name as path. So we can have:

```
GET /books/12
```

And if we want to fetch related collection, we might do:

```
GET /books/12/pages
```

On the other hand, there is a practice to use so-called *resource verbs* where you can fine-tune the verbs operation:

```
POST /books/12/bookmark
```

I would not use both approaches for my API. I tend to think that first approach is more correct (i.e. no verbs in resource name allowed), and to model the second approach we might use different entity, like:

```
POST /book-bookmarks/12/
```

or different id:

```
POST /bookmarks/12+book/
```

I know there is no true answer on this, but which one would be preferred? I would like to see some answers from people that actually went through design decisions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

URI (or IRI) is a [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) about indentifying resources. These resources can be web documents, real things, etc... In the current case they are web documents. Afaik. there is not standard about the URI structures, but URI standard along with HTTP standard suggest that you should use URIs and HTTP methods in a procedural way. So the HTTP verbs describe the procedure and the URIs identify the object of the procedure. Now you typically describe procedures with verbs and you typically describe objects with nouns. That's why it is logical to use only nouns in the URI structure, at least in the (hierarchical) path part of it.

(You usually can solve everything with the standard HTTP methods and proper nouns. Only in very special things can cause problems. In those cases I think it is better to use a new HTTP method than putting verbs into the URI. But that is really very rare. E.g. search with query string non compatible parameters e.g. files can be such a case. Another alternative approach in these cases to use POST and verbs in the URI.)